# Each set a timeout confirm last load and set a function

Tags: jquery

```
var J_lis = $(".display");

//J_lis.length = 4;

function test(){}

test.prototype._create = function(){
 alert("create");
}

test.prototype._loop = function(){
this._create();
}

test.prototype._set = function(){
var that = this;
J_lis.each(function(g,ele){

  var setSrc = this.src;
  var setId = this.id;
    setTimeout(function() {
      that._loop(setId, setSrc);
    }, (g+1)*2000);
}).promise().done(function () { alert("Everything is done."); });
}
```

I have a already set a timeout inside a each, I want the function to go each by each and each set a time for 2000, so it will create one by one, problem now is, I need to make sure the last each finish load **prototype_loop** and then i need to set a other function after all is done, something like jQuery promise

Process of function

```
display(wait for 2000)
display(wait for 2000)
display(wait for 2000)
display(wait for 2000)
```

Confirm the last display loaded and set a function for it.

How do I get going to achieve that? jQuery promise just won't work here.

Comment: `function test(){}`, `text.prototype`, typo?

Comment: oh sorry i will edit back.